# ResolvePackageNotFound: Create env using conda and yml file on MacOS

Tags: conda, virtual-environment

I want to create a virtual environment using conda and yml file.

Command:

```
conda env create -n ex3 -f env.yml
```

Type ENTER it gives following message:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:

 - gst-plugins-base==1.8.0=0
 - dbus==1.10.20=0
 - opencv3==3.2.0=np111py35_0
 - qt==5.6.2=5
 - libxcb==1.12=1
 - libgcc==5.2.0=0
 - gstreamer==1.8.0=0
```

However, I do have those on my Mac. My MacOS: High Sierra 10.13.3

My env.yml file looks like this:

```
name: ex3
channels:
- menpo
- defaults
dependencies:
- cairo=1.14.8=0
- certifi=2016.2.28=py35_0
- cycler=0.10.0=py35_0
- dbus=1.10.20=0
- expat=2.1.0=0
- fontconfig=2.12.1=3
- freetype=2.5.5=2
- glib=2.50.2=1
- gst-plugins-base=1.8.0=0
- gstreamer=1.8.0=0
- harfbuzz=0.9.39=2
- hdf5=1.8.17=2
- icu=54.1=0
- jbig=2.1=0
- jpeg=9b=0
- libffi=3.2.1=1
- libgcc=5.2.0=0
- libgfortran=3.0.0=1
- libiconv=1.14=0
- libpng=1.6.30=1
- libtiff=4.0.6=3
- libxcb=1.12=1
- libxml2=2.9.4=0
- matplotlib=2.0.2=np111py35_0
- mkl=2017.0.3=0
- numpy=1.11.3=py35_0
- openssl=1.0.2l=0
- pandas=0.20.1=np111py35_0
- patsy=0.4.1=py35_0
- pcre=8.39=1
- pip=9.0.1=py35_1
- pixman=0.34.0=0
- pyparsing=2.2.0=py35_0
- pyqt=5.6.0=py35_2
- python=3.5.4=0
- python-dateutil=2.6.1=py35_0
- pytz=2017.2=py35_0
- qt=5.6.2=5
- readline=6.2=2
- scipy=0.19.0=np111py35_0
- seaborn=0.8=py35_0
- setuptools=36.4.0=py35_1
- sip=4.18=py35_0
- six=1.10.0=py35_0
- sqlite=3.13.0=0
- statsmodels=0.8.0=np111py35_0
- tk=8.5.18=0
- wheel=0.29.0=py35_0
- xz=5.2.3=0
- zlib=1.2.11=0
- opencv3=3.2.0=np111py35_0
- pip:
  - bleach==1.5.0
  - enum34==1.1.6
  - html5lib==0.9999999
  - markdown==2.6.11
  - protobuf==3.5.1
  - tensorflow==1.4.1
  - tensorflow-tensorboard==0.4.0
  - werkzeug==0.14.1
```

How to solve this problem?

Well....The stack overflow prompt me to say more details, but I think I describe things clearly, it is sad, stack overflow does not support to upload attachment....

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce this, not sure the cause...

Comment: Maybe this file only works for Linux not for MacOS....

Answer (score 118):

I had same problem and found your question googling for it.

`ResolvePackageNotFound` error describes all packages not installed yet, but required.

To solve the problem, move them under `pip` section:

```
name: ex3
channels:
- menpo
- defaults
dependencies:
  - cairo=1.14.8=0
  - ***
  - another dependencies, except not found ones
  - pip:
    - gst-plugins-base==1.8.0                
    - bleach==1.5.0
    - enum34==1.1.6
    - html5lib==0.9999999
    - markdown==2.6.11
    - protobuf==3.5.1
    - tensorflow==1.4.1
    - tensorflow-tensorboard==0.4.0
    - werkzeug==0.14.1
    *** added ***
    - gst-plugins-base==1.8.0
    - dbus==1.10.20
    - opencv3==3.2.0
    - qt==5.6.2
    - libxcb==1.12
    - libgcc==5.2.0
    - gstreamer==1.8.0
```

Comment: I had the same issue, between two Ubuntu machines, so the suggestion of the OP that it could be related to different OSes does not seems to hold.
Your solution worked for me, but it is a bit of a shame to encounter dependency hell by using the system supposed to save us from it ;)

Comment: @LCT I've had the same problem with two Ubuntu machines as well.  I also agree that I don't think it's a matter of two different OS'.  My *guess* (and it would be great if someone can chime in here) is that some packages have been moved or have been deleted.  That is the difference between the two Ubuntu machines in my case -- a lot of time has passed.  About a year, I would say.  Somehow, I thought conda packages would "stay forever", but I guess I'm wrong?

Comment: it really depends on where your repo is available.  for my dependency i solved the issue by putting in `- conda-forge` as a channel under defaults.

Comment: None of the solutions helped me, does anyone have any other options?

Comment: If anyone is getting an error when conda tries to parse the newly altered file, it's worth noting that there needs to be TWO spaces indent for the pip subsection (as shown). I don't know why this is because I have a one space indent for the outer dependencies section and that works fine.

Comment: can anyone explain why the versions are == under pip but just = above?

Comment: @otocan This is because `pip` is nested under `dependencies`, and the items below are nested under `pip` :)  The indentation is the YAML syntax for showing hierarchies.
@PurpleVermont This is also why there are two `==` in the pip section - this is the syntax to say "install this version from pip", as opposed to above where the single `=` is there to say "check that you have exactly this version".

Comment: On MacOS (M1), I moved dependencies under `- pip:` which still got me a lot of errors. But when I removed versions completely, everything installed successfully. I'm assuming the config I have was created way back and maybe some of those versions didn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 30):

I got the same issue and found a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6073#issuecomment-356981567) related to this. In the comments, @kalefranz posted an ideal solution by using the `--no-builds` flag with conda env export.

```
conda env export --no-builds > environment.yml
```

However, even remove build numbers, some packages may still have different version number at different OS. The best way I think is to create different env yml file for different OS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This combining with @Northern Poet's answer help solve the problem.
The issue with Northern Peot's answer is that there is too many packages for me to search and move. Running this answer significantly reduces the number.

Comment: What's the command to create `different env yml file for different OS`? Say I am a developer working on  Ubuntu machine locally, how do I create three different (Windows, Mac, Ubuntu) requeirements file at the same time from within my local Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 8):

tl;dr `conda env export --from-history -n name_of_your_env -f environment.yml`

---

`conda env export` command pins your dependencies to the exact version along with OS specific details.

Looks like this for Pandas on macOS for example, `- pandas=1.0.5=py38h959d312_0`. `conda env create` cannot use this to create the same environment on other OS, like Linux inside Docker for instance.

So export the packages without pinning, and the ones you specifically installed after creating the conda environment, from history, using `conda env export --from-history`.

https://repo2docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/export_environment.html

Comment: I tried the above answers. The only one that solved the problem was this one.

Comment: ended up working with this command: conda env export --no-builds --from-history > environment.yml

Answer (score 5):

There can be another reason for the '**ResolvePackageNotFound**' error -- the version of the packages you require might be in an old version of the repository that is not searched by default.

The different paths to locations in the Anaconda repositories can be found at:
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/

My yml file [NW_BI.yml] is as follows:

```
name: NW_BI
channels:
- 'https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free' # Remove this line and it fails!!!
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- python=2.7.10
- pandas=0.16.2
- pyodbc=3.0.10
```

**Create using:**

```
conda env create -f 'path to file'\NW_BI.yml
```

I wanted to recreate an old environment!!!!

**Note using:**
Anaconda3 2019.10
Windows10

Answer (score 4):

Use `--no-builds` option to `conda env export`

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7311#issuecomment-442320274

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was able to work around it.  My issue wasn't related to pip but rather because the export platform wasn't the same as the import platform (Ref: nehaljwani's November 2018 answer on https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7311).

@Shixiang Wang's answer point towards a part of the solution.  The no-build argument allows for more flexibility but there are some components which are specific to the platform or OS.

Using the no-build export, I was able to identify (from the error message at import time) which libraries were problematic and simply removed them from the YML file.  This may not be flawless, but saves a lot of time compared to starting from scratch.

NOTE: I got a `Pip subprocess error` which interrupted the installation at a given library, which could be simply overcome via a `conda install <library>`.  From there I could relaunch the import from the YML file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at this and feel too much chore to change Conda version 
`packge=ver=py.*` to pip style `package==ver`, I wrote this small script that delete the `=py.*` part from Conda style.

Note below code work on the presume that you already changed `package=ver` to `package==ver`.

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNT=0
find_pip=0

while IFS= read -r line; do
    COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))
#    echo "$COUNT"
#    echo "read it"
    if echo ${line} | grep -q -- "- pip:" ; then
#        echo "find it"
        find_pip=1
        indent=`awk -F- '{print length($1)}' <<< "$line"`
        pip_indent=$(( $indent + 2 ))
#        echo $indent
#    echo $pip_indent
    fi

    line_indent=`awk -F- '{print length($1)}' <<< "$line"`

    if [[ ${find_pip} ]] && [[ ${pip_indent} -eq ${line_indent} ]]; then
#        echo "$line"
        new_line=`echo ${line} | cut -d'=' -f-3`
        new_line="    $new_line"
#        echo "${new_line}"
        sed -e "${COUNT}s/.*/${new_line}/" -i '' $1
    fi
done < "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the following command is used to create the environment.yml file : `conda env export --from-history -n envName -f environment1.yml` where envName is the name of the environment we are interested in. Assuming the content of the file is:

```
    name: envName
    channels:
      - defaults
    dependencies:
      - python=3.9
      - numpy
      - spyder
      - scipy
      - opencv==4.5.5
      - scikit-learn-intelex
      - shapely
      - imgaug
      - r-uuid
      - more-itertools
      - sympy
      - pylatex
      - progressbar2
    prefix: /home/User/anaconda3/envs/envName
```

Then add `- conda-forge` under `- defaults` in channels, And try to create the
environment again.

Answer (score 0):

For Apple ARM you should use another requirements:
https://github.com/magnusviri/stable-diffusion-old/blob/apple-silicon-mps-support/environment-mac.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You can use "conda env export --from-history > environment.yml" which will include only cross platform dependencies of conda.

And to include pip dependencies use "conda env export > temp.yml" and copy the pip related dependencies into the above file.

Now delete the temp.yml and use environment.yml for creating environment using the "conda env create -f environment.yml" command.