# Solving environment: failed when trying to set up Python virtual envrironment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I'm trying to set up a virtual environment using some code I've downloaded from github. the folder of code contains a file environment.yml. Instruction tells me to go into the code folder (Neural-Network-Projects-with-Python) via the anaconda command prompt and run this command.

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

However i get this error message

```
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - keras==2.2.4
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154899/resolvepackagenotfound-create-env-using-conda-and-yml-file-on-macos).
As mentioned there, you should move the dependency `keras==2.2.4` under `pip` section in `yml` file:

```
dependencies:
  ...
  - pip:
    - keras==2.2.4
    ...
```

Hope it helps!