# How to run project with the help conda

Tags: machine-learning, anaconda, conda, python-bob

I try to run project https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.paper.deep_pix_bis_pad.icb2019

I tried to use `anaconda 2022` and `anaconda 2016`

I use all commands that README contains

But I have different mistakes (a lot).

For example when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` I have:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-APyofd/bob.bio.base/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Does anybody know how to run this project?

I use `ubuntu 21.10`

**upd:**

Before `pip install -r requirements.txt` I try `conda env create -f environment.yml`

But I have `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libblitz==1.0.1 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for libblitz==1.0.1`.

**environment.yml**

```
  - pip:
    - dask==0.18.1
    - torch==0.4.1
    - cyvlfeat
    - dlib==19.7
    - ipdb==0.11
    - libblitz==1.0.1
    - libmatio=1.5.11
    - libsvm==3.22
    - menpo==0.8.1
    - menpofit==0.5.0
    - openh264==1.7.0
    - vlfeat==0.9.21
    - zc.buildout==2.11.2
    - zc.recipe.egg==2.0.5
```

Comment: The environment. yml that you have psoted does not match [the one from your link](https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.paper.deep_pix_bis_pad.icb2019/-/blob/master/environment.yml) Please try to create a conda env from that one

Comment: Yes. I have ```ResolvePackageNotFound: - cyvlfeat 0.4.6*``` then. I replace some necessary packages to ```- pip```. I try to use it like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154899/resolvepackagenotfound-create-env-using-conda-and-yml-file-on-macos

Comment: This does not work, most of these cannot be installed by pip. Stick with the original env, but try adding `- conda-forge` to the `channels` section

Comment: Thanks. Then I have ```ResolvePackageNotFound:  - cyvlfeat 0.4.6*```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I use ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 0):

Is the conda env active? Perhaps it is not running through conda?

As shown here: https://datumorphism.leima.is/til/programming/python/python-anaconda-install-requirements/

```
conda install pip
conda create -n yourenv pip
conda activate yourenv
pip install -r requirements.txt
```