# Unable to install mkl-service using conda

Tags: python, macos, conda

Trying to install mkl-service in a new conda environment keeps failing with the following error message:

```
Error while loading conda entry point: conda-libmamba-solver (dlopen(/Users/yavor/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/libmambapy/bindings.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libarchive.19.dylib
  Referenced from: <9391E88D-A5AA-33C9-8306-75BC6FFBC365> /Users/yavor/anaconda3/lib/libmamba.2.0.0.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/Users/yavor/anaconda3/lib/libarchive.19.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/yavor/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/libmambapy/../../../libarchive.19.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/yavor/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/libmambapy/../../../libarchive.19.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/yavor/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libarchive.19.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/yavor/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libarchive.19.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libarchive.19.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libarchive.19.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache))
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - mkl-service

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - [...] /conda-forge/noarch
  - [...] /free/osx-arm64
  - [...] /free/noarch
  - [...] /menpo/osx-arm64
  - [...] /menpo/noarch
  - [...] /default/osx-arm64
  - [...] /default/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - [...] /pkgs/main/noarch
  - [...] /pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - [...] /pkgs/r/noarch
```

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Computer is Apple M1 Pro, OS Ventura 13.4.1 (c)
Relatively fresh (1 month old) installation of Anaconda.

History: Initially tried to create new environment with:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

envirnonment.yml file was:

name: neural-network-projects-python
dependencies:

- python==3.6.8
- pandas==0.23.4
- numpy==1.15.4
- matplotlib==3.0.2
- Keras==2.2.4
- opencv==3.4.2
- seaborn==0.9.0
- scikit-learn==0.20.2
- mkl-service==1.1.2
- theano==1.0.3
- pillow==5.4.1
- ipykernel==5.1.0
- jupyter
- pip:

  - piexif==1.1.2

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154899/resolvepackagenotfound-create-env-using-conda-and-yml-file-on-macos), tried including channels in the environment.yml (didn't work) moving all dependancies under -pip: (didn't work), then removed the versions and it worked up to the mkl-service package, tried `conda install -c conda-forge mkl-service` (didn't work).

Now I have the environment installed and activated, but still cannot install mkl-service.

*Note: I manually removed some of the links from the above error message (exchanged them for [...]), because Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post more than 10 links in a single question. Hope this is OK.

Answer (score 0):

MKL is not compatible with **osx-arm64** - it's an Intel-specific optimized library that does not run on Apple Silicon.